# Provide a proof for the following statement:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f : X → Y$ be any function. Show that $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ for any
$A ⊂ X$.

I understand the logic behind this and why it would be true. However, I am unsure of the method that someone would go about proving this.

Comment: The standard procedure would be: Let $A$ be a subset of $X$ and let $x$ be an element of $A$, then prove that $x$ must be an element of $f^{-1}(f(A))$. One has to consider the case when $A$ is empty.

Comment: @J.E.Bejarano: No, one exactly _doesn't_ need to consider $A=\varnothing$ as a special case. (The claim will be vacuously true.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was trying to make emphasis on "considering all the cases".

Comment: Of course the notation is very ambiguous. If $X=Y=\{\emptyset\}$ and $f$ is the identity map then $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ could refer either to $\emptyset$ or $\{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subset X $ and $x\in A $.

$$x\in A \implies f (x)\in f (A) $$

$$\implies x\in f^{-1}(f (A)) $$

thus $A\subset f^{-1}(f (A)) $

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the the definitions.

$f(A) = \{f(a)| a \in A\}$

$f^{-1}(B) \{y \in X| \exists\ b\in B; f(y)=b\}$

Let $x \in A$.  Then  $f(x) \in f(A)$. so $f(x)$ is an $f(x) \in f(A)$ so that $f(x) = f(x)$.  So $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$.

So $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$.

(Assuming that there is any $x \in A$.... If there aren't then $A = \emptyset$ and ....)